# How can I view nodes on my site from Drupalgap?

Tags: javascript

I am getting started with Drupalgap and trying to access nodes on my Drupal site by node ID from within Drupalgap.  I have checked the [Node](http://www.drupalgap.org/node/197) and [Node Services](http://www.drupalgap.org/node/86) documentation.  I thought I could use the [node_page_view(nid)](http://api.drupalgap.org/node.js.html) function like this:

```
function mymodule_sample_page() {
  try {
    node_load(11, {
        success:function(node){
        alert("Loaded " + node.title);
      }
    });
    return node_page_view(11);
  }
  catch (error) { console.log('mymodule_sample_page - ' + error); }
}
```

However, when I attempt to test this in my module, I get the alert "Loaded your node" but the content is not actually displayed on the page by **node_page_view()**.  What do I need to do to display the content?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `mymodule_sample_page()` just return an empty div container, for example:

`<div id="my_node_11"></div>`

Then attach a `pageshow` handler to your page via `hook_menu()`, then in the pageshow handler call node_load(), and in its success inject the content into your empty div container.

The `page_callback` can not have any async calls in it, as all async calls have to be handled after the page is actually shown.

FYI, DrupalGap has built in support to view nodes, just navigate to `node/11` in the app. Here's a brief example demonstrating pageshow: http://www.drupalgap.org/node/154

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Tyler. I put the answer with more detail and proven by my successful experiment. Hope this can do some helps.

```
function mymodule_sample_page() {
  var display_page = '<div id="my_node_11"></div>'; 

  return display_page;
}

function mymodule_sample_pageshow() {
  try{
        var nid = 11;
        node_load(nid, {
        success:function(node){

         var content = node.content;

         $('#' + 'my_node_' + nid).html(content).trigger('create');
          }
        });
   }
  catch (error) { console.log('mymodule_sample_page - ' + error); }
}
```